# Deploying API management policy having Named value between {{named_value}}

Tags: continuous-deployment, azure-api-management, terraform-provider-azure, apim

So we Have Automated Api management Policy To Azure Apim with below video reference.
https://youtu.be/4Sp2Qvmg6j8

Now thing is We are using Named value in our Policy.xml file like {{named_value}}.

So while Deploying ot we are getting Error like "Validation Error"
"Either Value or Keyvault must be provided".

I know we can Use Xml transformation To replace {{named_value}} with Keyvault or CI's Variables , It makes that named value in that Policy.xml hardcoded. So with this everytime we have to change Value in Keyvault then do Deployment. This is what we don't want.

We want to that named value to remain as it is {{named_value}} & to take value from Apim's Named value so that when we change value in Named value we don't need to deploy Policy Again.

Can Someone Help us please, like Can we use somesort of Escape charector or How to deploy Policy with named value {{named_value}} as it is.

We tried xml transformation to replace that {{named_value}} But we don't want this.

Comment: Can you share your policy xml?

Comment: Problem was Fixed . What mistake we were doing is we were Deploying apim policy directly first before creating named value in apim .IN ORDER to Deploy apim policy with Named value we have to ensure named value exists . If not then we will get error.

Comment: Same goes for Policy Fragment. In this also we can use Named Value and whole policy fragment we can use in apim policy .What we have tried based on that sequence of Deployment will be 1. Named Value - as we can use this in policy Fragment as well as Normal operation policy. 2. Policy Fragment - if we are using Policy fragment in apim policy then first this policy fragment should be present. 3. Normal Operation Policy - in that Named Value or Fragment we will Use .https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/policy-fragments

Comment: Additionally Adding One more Thing , we were getting Apim policy Size limit 16 KB Exceeded problem. We have tried to find it's Solution but We we're not able to . After going threw Azure and Microsoft Documentation, giving suggestions from personal Perspective  : 1. all Operations Policy - we can use rate limit over there but suppose every underneath method requires authentication then you can put that part in All operation policy so that When actual Method we call then All Operation policy will get call first as Parent and then As child individual method Policy. 2 . Policy Fragments